# Proper use of KeepAlive in Apache Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header, keep-alive

What is the difference between:

`Header set Connection keep-alive`

and

`KeepAlive on`

in Apache htaccess?

What code and options we have to put in the header of a php file? And what in htaccess file?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you simply set the header `Connection: keep-alive` it isn't going to be enough. The client will think it's a keep-alive connection but the server may decide to close the connection. Additionally, the client doesn't know how many requests can be served through the keep-alive connection. There's an additional header that is used to track requests sent through a keep-alive connection that looks like this:

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
```

which tells the client that it can send up to 100 more requests on the current keep-alive connection (and it counts down as you continue to use said keep-alive connection) and that the client has 15 seconds to make any additioanl requests before the connection is closed.

Simply using the header isn't sufficient to establish a keep alive connection because the server needs to negotiate it. Both ends need to know about the keep-alive and both ends need to do proper accounting. You need to tell apache to handle keep-alive on its end and simply sending the header isn't going to do that. You need to turn keep-alive on using the second directive:

```
KeepAlive on
```

And additionally, you can tweak the keep-alive mechanism with directives like:

```
KeepAliveTimeout 15
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin that is one awesome clear well written answer! Wish you a Good day I will contact my server admins.

Comment: On shared hosting the use of KeepAlive is often not allowed: when putting it in .htaccess the server says `Error occurred: 500 - internal server error`   :( :( :(

Comment: `<ifModule mod_headers.c> Header set Connection keep-alive </ifModule>` worked for me on my shared hosting
source: http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html

Comment: Dear @Jon thanks (again) for this amazing insight. Can you please clarify: what kind of code goes into the `page.php` file's header, and what code goes into Apache's `.htaccess`? in a shared hosting environment with comment from @retrovertigo included in it, thanks and Cheers mate! I've set a bounty for this :)

Comment: @Sam if your hosting provider won't allow you to use the `KeepAlive` directive in yuor htaccess file, then I don't think there's anything you can do with your php scripts to enable keep alive. Not sure how retrovertigo's suggestion works if the underlying apache mechanism has keep alive turned OFF.

Comment: Can anyone tell what's the maximum timeout we can have for keep-alive. I remember I read somewhere it can't be more than the TCP connection timeout but am not sure?

Comment: @JonLin What is the disadvantage if we don't use KeepAliveTimeout & MaxKeepAliveRequests in server config ? I want to know this use-case consider this keepAlive is turned on server and client is sending request with keepAlive header and it will be a persistent connection. 

Now if client is sending request in every 1 second then TCP connection will be same. Does a new socket will be created for each request  ?