# Apache CFX (wsdl2java) generated SOAP Client closes connections after 5s

Tags: java, soap, timeout, keep-alive, wsdl2java

I have a SOAP client generated with apache-cxf(v3.3.2).
The client runs inside a Spring Boot application using embedded Tomcat.

How can I specify the keep-alive timeout for this SOAP client?

What I found so far:

The socket used for establishing the connection closes after 5s. 
This timeout is a hardcoded default in the underlying sun.net.www.http.HttpClient. **It is not controlled by the tomcat connection-timeout or com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout properties.** 
The HttpClient.keepAliveTimeout variable is set only if the Server responds with a Keep-Alive header (e.g. Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100 ): [see line 752](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/http/HttpClient.java).

The server doesn't provide this header.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155201/http-keep-alive-timeout) this is the expected behaviour, but is it really:

> The client cannot specify the timeout, it is the server configuration
>   that determines the maximum timeout value. The extra Keep-Alive header
>   can inform the client how long the server is willing to keep the
>   connection open ...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it directly via HTTPClientPolicy. I use this in my CXF client.

```
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        // Set connection timeout
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
        httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(30000);

        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```